# Mutate changes full column instead of row by row

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, stringr

In a dataframe, I want to create a new column based on the occurence of a specific set of strings (char vector) in another column.

So basically, I want this:

```
ID  Phrases
1   some words
2   some words dec
3   some words nov may
```

to return this:

```
ID  Phrases             MonthsOccur
1   some words          NA
2   some words dec      dec
3   some words nov may  may nov
```

I have tried the following, and I'm not sure why it's giving me the outcome that it does:

```
library(dplyr)

vMonths <- c("jan","feb","mar","apr","may","jun","jul","aug","sept","nov","dec")

a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c('phrase number one', 'phrase dec','phrase nov')

df <- data.frame(a,b)
names(df) <- c("ID","Phrases")
df <- df %>% mutate(MonthsOccur = paste(vMonths[str_detect(Phrases, vMonths)],collapse=" "))
```

It gives me the following warning:

> Warning message:
>   In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

And the following outcome:

```
ID  Phrases             MonthsOccur
1   some words          dec
2   some words dec      dec
3   some words nov may  dec
```

Comment: Side note: `tolower(month.abb)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to apply `str_detect` `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(MonthsOccur = paste0(vMonths[str_detect(Phrases, vMonths)], 
                       collapse = " "))
```

However, `rowwise` may or may not be continued in the future so a better way is to use `map` operations

```
df %>%
  mutate(MonthsOccur = purrr::map_chr(Phrases,  
                      ~paste0(vMonths[str_detect(.x, vMonths)], collapse = " ")))

#  ID           Phrases MonthsOccur
#1  1 phrase number one            
#2  2        phrase dec         dec
#3  3    phrase nov may     may nov
```

---

A base R option would be with `regmatches` and `gregexpr`

```
sapply(regmatches(df$Phrases, gregexpr(paste0(vMonths, collapse = "|"),
        df$Phrases)), paste0, collapse = " ")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3), Phrases = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("phrase dec", "phrase nov may", "phrase number one"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks -- worked like a charm! Any insights into why this seems to be working  differently vs other functions used in ```mutate``` (which seem to be working row by row anyhow)? Can't seem to figure out why it did what it does.

Comment: @BroQ well, that is because `str_detect` is vectorized over both `string` and `pattern`. So `Phrases[1]` is compared with `vMonths[1]`, `Phrases[2]` is compared with `vMonths[2]`. So you don't get all the matches that you are expecting. By specifying `rowwise` or using `map` we are comparing `Phrases[1]` with all `vMonths`, then `Phrases[2]` with all `vMonths` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Another option involving `dplyr` and `stringr` could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(MonthsOccur = str_extract_all(Phrases, paste(tolower(month.abb), collapse = "|")))

  ID            Phrases MonthsOccur
1  1         some words            
2  2     some words dec         dec
3  3 some words nov may    nov, may
```

The output here is not a character vector, but a list.

If you are indeed looking for a character vector, then with the addition of `purrr`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(MonthsOccur = map_chr(str_extract_all(Phrases, paste(tolower(month.abb), collapse = "|")), 
                              paste, collapse = ", "))
```